Why are some checkout hooks not working in WooCommerce?
I'm using the following code to save the value of a hidden input field having as attribute name "custom_form_data":
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_custom_form_data_to_order');
function save_custom_form_data_to_order($order_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['custom_form_data'])) {
        $custom_form_data = sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_form_data']);
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'custom_form_data', $custom_form_data);
    }
}

But the submitted value is not saved to the database. I Checked on wp_postmeta and wp_wc_orders_meta tables.
Why is woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta hook not working?

This can be related to 2 different things:

High-Performance Order Storage is enabled:

Note that High-Performance Order Storage (HPOS) is now enabled by default.
If HPOS is enabled, you need to use instead a compatible hook, like:
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_custom_form_data_to_order');
function save_custom_form_data_to_order( $order ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['custom_form_data']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( 'custom_form_data', sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_form_data']) );
    }
}

Or you could use alternatively the following (requires using the save() method):
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'save_custom_form_data_to_order');
function save_custom_form_data_to_order( $order ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['custom_form_data']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( 'custom_form_data', sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_form_data']) );
        $order->save();
    }
}

With HPOS, WordPress Post meta functions doesn't work any more as WooCommerce orders use custom database tables for better performances.
So HPOS requires to use WC_Data, WC_Abstract_Order or WC_Order methods on the WC_Order object.
So to get/read the value from your custom field, you will use something like:
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // If needed get the WC_Order object

$value = $order->get_meta('custom_form_data'); // Get custom field value



Checkout Blocks is enabled:

Note that Checkout Blocks is now enabled by default, and only allows very few customizations.
The following action hooks won't work when using Checkout Blocks:

woocommerce_checkout_create_order (compatible with HPOS)
woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta
woocommerce_checkout_order_created (compatible with HPOS)
and many more…

The alternative is to switch back to legacy classic Checkout (shortcode).

Hey man, honestly you made my day!!! You are legend!!! Your detailed answer helped me, and issue got fixed!!! Thanks again!

I changed it in one line (but it took me 3 hours).
this: woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_custom_form_data_to_order');

to this: woocommerce_update_order
add_action('woocommerce_update_order', 'save_custom_form_data_to_order');

and it worked (adding new data to the order on the checkout page)
